# JSON Handling Quick

Tags: android, json

Hey guys this is the first time I am doing JSON and I have gotten the json from the server. Now my only question is how do I take the data.

The JSON includes

```
 [

  {


  "name": "Joe Smith",

    "employeeId":1,

    "company": "ABC",

    "phone": {
        "work": "555-555-5555",
        "home": "666-666-6666",
        "mobile": "777-777-7777"
    }
},
{
    "name": "Does Smith",
    "employeeId":2,
    "company": "XYZ",
    "phone": {
        "work": "111-111-1111",
        "home": "222-222-2222",
        "mobile": "333-333-3333"
    }
}
```

]

jsonData is my string of the JSON
Currently I have:

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONOBject(jsonData);
    JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject(*******)
    JSONArray phones = data.getJSONArray("phone");
```

not sure what to put on the second line. Also, what is the best way to group the information. 
Please make it easy to understand, not exactly a professional yet haha

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your first line is wrong because current string is `JSONArray` of JSONObject's so get data from current string as:

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonData);
for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++){
      JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject(i);

       // get name,employeeId,... from data
        String str_name=data.optString("work");
         //...
      JSONObject jsonobjphones = data.getJSONObject("phone");

      // get work from phone JSONObject
      String str_work=jsonobjphones.optString("work");
      //....
 }
```

Comment: I am kind of confused as to how to group the data. I feel like it should be an array of objects where each object has a name, id, company, and phone number array. I just don't know how to implement it. Ultimately I want to have access to all the information. I feel like the above code is for temporary assignment since data will change without the information being stored

Comment: @user3311987 : use ArrayList of Map to store each person data in ArrayList.

Comment: Do you think it is a good idea to have six arrays and populate them with the code given above? I could just make them string arrays? One for name, company, id, mobile, work, home?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
           List list=new ArrayList();
        JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(str_response_starter);

        JSONArray json_array_item_id = jObject.getJSONArray("itemid");
        System.out.println("json array item id"+json_array_item_id);

        JSONArray json_array_item_name = jObject.getJSONArray("itemname");
        System.out.println("json array item name"+json_array_item_name);


        JSONArray json_array_item_type = jObject.getJSONArray("type");
        System.out.println("json array item type"+json_array_item_type);

        JSONArray json_array_item_cost = jObject.getJSONArray("cost");
        System.out.println("json array item cost"+json_array_item_cost);
```

Now

```
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(kvPairs.size());
                   String k, v;
                   Iterator<String> itKeys = kvPairs.keySet().iterator();

                   while (itKeys.hasNext()) {                         
                          k = itKeys.next();     
                          System.out.println(" value of k"+k);
                          v = kvPairs.get(k);
                          System.out.println(" value of v"+v);
```

Comment: Will this give me four arrays where all of them have hold either name, id, company, or phone numbers?

Comment: Now further you can iterate form all JsonArray.

Answer (score 0):

In JSON, `[]` represents `JSONArray`, `{}` represents `JSONObject`. In your JSON string, it starts with `[`, so you need to start with `JSONArray`:

```
JSONArray people = new JSONArray(jsonData);
```

And then you'll notice that each person is a `JSONObject`, so now you need to loop them in order to get their information:

```
for(int i=0;i<people.length();i++){
  JSONObject person = people.getJSONObject(i); 
  JSONObject phones = person.getJSONObject("phone"); //phone is also a JSONObject, because it starts with '{'
  String workPhone = phones.get("work");
}
```

Comment: do i need the for loop? Isn't the array enough to get all of the information? Then we can just use the array when we need something?

Comment: The thing is that for each `JSONObject`, their isn't any name assigned to it, that's why you need to loop them, otherwise you can access each object by the name, then you don't need to loop.